# How to get a value from a Listbox in HTML Service

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, listbox

I am having a problem with HTML Service in Google Apps Script. I am trying to get a value from a listbox to pull and populate the rest of a form. This worked great when using `uiApp` but since Google has decided to shut-down `uiApp` next month, I have no choice but to migrate all my apps to HTML Service.

I have found some bites on using scriptlets here on stackoverflow but I keep getting Errors.

HTML

```
<form>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><label>Select Clinic:</label></td>
  <td><select name="selectClinic"id="selectClinic"onchange="doThisOnChange(this.value)"> 
  </select>

  <script>
    doThisOnChange = function(value)
    {
    alert( "Do something with the value: " + value );
    <?!=
    var ClinicID =  value;
    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyID");
    var sheet= SS.getSheetByName('Data');
    var getClinicName = sheet.getRange("D"+ClinicID+":D"+ClinicID);
    window.document.getElementById("clinicName").value = getClinicName ; 
    ?>          
    }
    </script>

    <tr>
    <td><label>Clinic Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="clinicName" id="clinicName" value=""> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

It appears that the script is not able to get the value passed when a scriptlet is used. Getting the error

> "ReferenceError: "value" is not defined. (line 5, file "Code")"

I was finally able to get the form to populate the fields by using the `window.document.getElementById` method, but it appears that the script stops when a scriptlet is not used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

You are mixing up *server-side* component that runs *only once* on template evaluation (scriplets) and *client-side* script. Thus, `value` used as an `doThisOnChange` argument can't be accessed in the scriplet.

**Solution**

If you need to call server-side component more than once, you should use the `google.script.run` API instead as this is the only way of communicating with server-side functions.

**Sample**

So, if I understood your goal correctly, you should decouple your code like this (please, note that it is important for the server-side function to explicitly `return` the desired output + you set a `withSuccessHandler()` to perform client-side actions on server-side function successful run result):

*Server-side*

```
function getClinicName(ClinicID) {
  var OPCDSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyID"); //I assume SS === OPCDSS?;
  var sheet = OPCDSS.getSheetByName('Data');
  var range = sheet.getRange("D"+ClinicID+":D"+ClinicID);
  var name  = range.getValue(); //this part was originally missing;
  return name;    
}
```

*Client-side*

```
  <script>
    /**
     * Asynchronously calls server-side function;
     * @param {String} value clinic select value; 
     */
    function doThisOnChange (value) {
      alert( "Do something with the value: " + value );
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillName).getClinicName(value);
    }

    /**
     * Performs client-side actions on server-side function return;
     * @param {*} serverOutput value returned from server-side;
     */
    function fillName (serverOutput) {
      var clinicNameInput = document.getElementById('clinicName');
          clinicNameInput.value = serverOutput;
    }
</script>
```

**Multiple server-side fields**

As discussed in comments, added an example of working with multi-column and / or row `Range` instances. If you call a `getValues()` method on a `Range`, the resulting `Array` of values to iterate on will be structured as:

```
[ //pseudo-code;
  row1 [ col1 , ..., colN ] ,
  ...,
  rowN [ col1, ..., colN ] 
]
```

Please, note that working on 2D `Array` instances is just a best practice since `getValue()` / `getValues()` methods are computationally heavy. To sum up, instead of directly returning the `name` of the clinic, you would create an `Object` instance containing all clinic properties (that can be later referenced in client-side callback function by `key`) or you can simply pass return the `Array` and work on it client-side:

```
function getData(ClinicID) {
  var ss     = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyID");
  var sheet  = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var range  = sheet.getRange(yourRangeboundaries); 
  var values = range.getValues(); //gets 2D Array of values;

  var output = {}; //initiate output Object;

  output.name = values[0][0]; //assuming name is in 1st row 1st column;
  output.phone = values[0][4]; //assuming phone is in 1st row 5th column;
  //etc;

  return output;
}
```

**Useful notes**

Client-to-server communication with `google.script.run` is *asynchronous* in nature, which means that you *don't have to wait* until your server-side function finishes to perform other tasks, but at the same time you can only access server-side results *in scope of a callback* function.

**Useful links**

1. Templated HTML [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates);
2. Client-to-server communication [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication);
3. `google.script.run` API [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run);
4. `getValue()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue);

Comment: Yes, I think were on the right track, however when I try to amend the solution you offered, it still does not work. 

What I am trying to do is gather data (clinicID) from the selectClinic listbox. Then by using that ID, gathering the data from the spreadsheet to populate the formfields with that clinics information (name, phone number, fax number, email). 
Its strange, I believe that this should work too but Google is not letting it.

Comment: Hi, @DerykP! I overlooked a problem with your server-side component initially - you should extract value ( or values with `getValues()` ) from the `Range`, otherwise it is not a valid data type to return to client-side!

Comment: Yes!! That worked. I must have over looked the getValues in my original code. Is there a way I can populate additional fields using the same script? (eg: the phone number [E] fax number [F], email [G] from the spreadsheet). You have been super helpful @oleg

Comment: NP! Ofc, you can populate anything - `fillName` + `getClinicName` is only an example of what you can do (just reference a wider `Range`, extract the values with `getValues()`, iterate over 2D `Array` of retrieved values, then output into `Array` or `Object` - server-side + in client side - reference multiple fields)

Comment: One again, thanks @oleg. You truly understand what I am trying to accomplish here. Any possibility you can give me a example of iterating over a 2D array for 2 rows? I tried and I keep getting undefined. Maybe I am not understanding it correctly (new to this type of programming).

Comment: @DerykP, sure, check the updated answer in some time from now, I'll add 2D `Array` handling to the example!

Comment: Thanks @oleg. Still a bit confused on how to get the data over to the form. I understand the part where you created the array, but how do I obtain that information in the client script? Im getting the result: [object Object] in my fields currently. As well can you clarify by what you mean ' var range = sheet.getRange(yourRangeboundaries); ' my spreadsheet goes to AC (so would my range be A:AC?

Comment: Sure - in your client side you should access object's *properties*, for example, `serverOutput.name`, etc (the `[object Object]` result means that you tried to "write" object into a cell instead of `String`, `Number` and so on. As for the boundaries, there are quite a bunch of ways to ref. a range, so I added a placeholder (usually its either a comma separated 1-based ref: (row,col,num rows, num cols) or A1 notation: An:ACn)